# Android Launcing Google Maps Directions From Variable

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to Launcing Google Maps Directions from Variable edittext or textview anybody help me?
this is my java code :

```
    StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=");
    double d = -6.559759;
    StringBuilder stringbuilder1 = stringbuilder.append(d).append(",");
    double d1 = 106.785973;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(stringbuilder1.append(d1).toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What is the problem? does it crash? post the logcat and/or stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
   final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr="+currentLatitude+","+currentLongitude+"&daddr="+dest_Latitude+","+dest_Longitude));
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: like this?? can help me check the eror?? public void onClickShowMap(View v) {
       String latitude = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude)).getText().toString();
       String longitude = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude)).getText().toString();
       
  Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,   
   Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude));
  startActivity(intent);
  }